# Qt Qml : debug events propagation

Tags: qt, debugging, qml

I'm trying to debug a big qml application. I wanted to know if it's possible to show the propagation of a mouse event. Ex: if I click on the application I want to know which item(s) receive the press event and if multiple items receive it (because of propagation) I wanted to know if it's possible to show in which order they receive the event.

I need something general that doesn't force me to modify the whole qml (there are thousands of qml files, it's not feasible to modify each of them to provide debug information).

Is it possible with Qt/Qml ?